# Создание собственного элемента управления на C++

Tags: c++, winworms

Создал статический элемент управления и пытаюсь изменить его цвет,но ничего не выходит.
   файл CMyControl.cpp

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
#include "CMyControl.h"

// место для  других include


#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// место для кода реализации
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyControl, CStatic)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


void CMyControl::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting
                       // TODO: добавьте свой код обработчика сообщений
                       // Не вызывать CStatic::OnPaint() для сообщений рисования
                       // прямоугольник клиентской области
    CRect r_CL;
    GetClientRect(&r_CL);

    // определение высоты и ширины клиентской области
    int Hig = r_CL.Height();
    int Wid = r_CL.Width();
    dc.FillSolidRect(-1000, -10, Wid + 2000, Hig + 20, RGB(0, 255, 0));//зелёный
    dc.FillSolidRect(-20, -20, Wid + 40, Hig + 40, RGB(0, 0, 0));//чёрный
    dc.FillSolidRect(0, 0, Wid, Hig, RGB(255, 0, 0));//красный
}
```

файл CMyControl.h
    #pragma once

```
class CMyControl :public CStatic
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CMyControl)
public:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    afx_msg

    void OnPaint();
};
```

Comment: Скачай qt и не мучайся

Comment: Мне нужно с нуля его сделать

Comment: возьми qt и сделай с нуля. Нуль понятие растяжимое